# Using INSERT INTO and setting one field value - Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm using INSERT INTO to copy rows of data from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO tblNewCustomers (CustomerID, [Last Name], [First Name])
SELECT CustomerID, [Last Name], [First Name]
FROM tblOldCustomers
```

How can I set one of the field values in tblNewCustomers for all of the new records that I am importing in withn this statement e.g

```
tblNewCustomers.existCustomer = TRUE
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Noel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tblNewCustomers (CustomerID, [Last Name], 
    [First Name], [existCustomer])
SELECT CustomerID, [Last Name], [First Name], True 
FROM tblOldCustomers
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Smandoli. Hoped it would be simple to do, I had no idea how to structure it.

Comment: @Daniel Dolz:  Yes, you are right -- setting a default value in the table is usually the straightforward solution.  But using SQL opens up many possibilities -- inserting different values, most obviously.  In particular for Union queries, this SQL device "disambiguates" the table source and forces distinct rows:  
   SELECT *, "A" AS Marker FROM tbl_a 
   UNION 
   SELECT *, "B" AS Marker FROM tbl_b

Answer (score 0):

You can also ignore the field in the SQL sentence and make it have a default in true.
BUT I think Smandoli solution is more accurate